# How to modify this script to capture photos continuously?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am able to capture single photo using this script. How should I modify this script to capture photos continuously to render it on 3D plane? I want to pass that "targetTexture" to some function continuously.

```
public class PhotoCaptureExample : MonoBehaviour
{
    PhotoCapture photoCaptureObject = null;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start ()
    {
        PhotoCapture.CreateAsync(false, OnPhotoCaptureCreated);
    }

    void OnPhotoCaptureCreated(PhotoCapture captureObject)
    {
        photoCaptureObject = captureObject;

        Resolution cameraResolution = PhotoCapture.SupportedResolutions
            .OrderByDescending((res) => res.width * res.height).First();

        CameraParameters c = new CameraParameters();
        c.hologramOpacity = 0.0f;
        c.cameraResolutionWidth = cameraResolution.width;
        c.cameraResolutionHeight = cameraResolution.height;
        c.pixelFormat = CapturePixelFormat.BGRA32;

        captureObject.StartPhotoModeAsync(c, OnPhotoModeStarted);
    }

    void OnStoppedPhotoMode(PhotoCapture.PhotoCaptureResult result)
    {
        photoCaptureObject.Dispose();
        photoCaptureObject = null;
    }

    private void OnPhotoModeStarted(PhotoCapture.PhotoCaptureResult result)
    {
        if (result.success)
        {
            photoCaptureObject.TakePhotoAsync(OnCapturedPhotoToMemory);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.LogError("Unable to start photo mode!");
        }
    }

    void OnCapturedPhotoToMemory(PhotoCapture.PhotoCaptureResult result, 
        PhotoCaptureFrame photoCaptureFrame)
    {
        if (result.success)
        {
            // Create our Texture2D for use and set the correct resolution
            Resolution cameraResolution = PhotoCapture.SupportedResolutions
                .OrderByDescending((res) => res.width * res.height).First();
            Texture2D targetTexture = new Texture2D(cameraResolution.width, 
                cameraResolution.height);

            // Copy the raw image data into our target texture
            photoCaptureFrame.UploadImageDataToTexture(targetTexture);
            // Do as we wish with the texture such as apply it to a material, etc.
        }
        // Clean up
        photoCaptureObject.StopPhotoModeAsync(OnStoppedPhotoMode);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () 
    {           
    }
}
```

Comment: This sounds related maybe https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/158518/99708

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Afaik you can not make a new `TakePhotoAsync` call every frame but have to wait until the current process finished. It is to performance intense and afaik also gets exclusive permission to access the camera device so any other call fails meanwhile.

---

In order to wait with the next photo until before one is finished in `OnCapturedPhotoToMemory` you could simply instead of

```
photoCaptureObject.StopPhotoModeAsync(OnStoppedPhotoMode);
```

call the next photo

```
photoCaptureObject.TakePhotoAsync(OnCapturedPhotoToMemory);
```

---

Maybe you should add an exit condition right before it like a `private bool shouldStop` like

```
if(shouldStop)
{
    photoCaptureObject.StopPhotoModeAsync(OnStoppedPhotoMode);
}
else
{
    photoCaptureObject.TakePhotoAsync(OnCapturedPhotoToMemory);
}
```

---

**However**, be aware that this will slow down your App drastically! Since most of the `Texture2D` stuff happens on the main thread and is quite performance intense!

Answer (score 0):

This is far from perfect and I have not tested it, but something like this should work. Though, you may want the while loop inside of a async void method so it doesn't freeze your application.

```
public class PhotoCaptureExample : MonoBehaviour
{
PhotoCapture photoCaptureObject = null;
bool capturing = false;

// Use this for initialization
void Start ()
{
    PhotoCapture.CreateAsync(false, OnPhotoCaptureCreated);
}

void OnPhotoCaptureCreated(PhotoCapture captureObject)
{
    photoCaptureObject = captureObject;

    Resolution cameraResolution = PhotoCapture.SupportedResolutions
        .OrderByDescending((res) => res.width * res.height).First();

    CameraParameters c = new CameraParameters();
    c.hologramOpacity = 0.0f;
    c.cameraResolutionWidth = cameraResolution.width;
    c.cameraResolutionHeight = cameraResolution.height;
    c.pixelFormat = CapturePixelFormat.BGRA32;

    captureObject.StartPhotoModeAsync(c, OnPhotoModeStarted);
}

void OnStoppedPhotoMode(PhotoCapture.PhotoCaptureResult result)
{
    photoCaptureObject.Dispose();
    photoCaptureObject = null;
}

private void OnPhotoModeStarted(PhotoCapture.PhotoCaptureResult result)
{
    if (result.success)
    {
        capturing = true
        while(capturing)
        {
            try
            {
                photoCaptureObject.TakePhotoAsync(OnCapturedPhotoToMemory);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                // Do something
                capturing = false;
                // Clean up
                photoCaptureObject.StopPhotoModeAsync(OnStoppedPhotoMode);
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.LogError("Unable to start photo mode!");
    }
}

void OnCapturedPhotoToMemory(PhotoCapture.PhotoCaptureResult result, 
    PhotoCaptureFrame photoCaptureFrame)
{
    if (result.success)
    {
        // Create our Texture2D for use and set the correct resolution
        Resolution cameraResolution = PhotoCapture.SupportedResolutions
            .OrderByDescending((res) => res.width * res.height).First();
        Texture2D targetTexture = new Texture2D(cameraResolution.width, 
            cameraResolution.height);

        // Copy the raw image data into our target texture
        photoCaptureFrame.UploadImageDataToTexture(targetTexture);
        // Do as we wish with the texture such as apply it to a material, etc.
    }
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () 
{
    if(!capturing)
    {
        // to ensure the photos are continuously being captured
        Start();
    }           
}
}
```

Comment: You may want to look at the code again. It creates the photoCaptureObject once. Then sets capturing to true, and starts the while loop. It only stops the capturing and disposes of the photoCaptureObject if there is an exception. Then the Update method only calls for it to start again if capturing is false. Which would mean there was an exception thrown. Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes sorry just realized it ;) problem anyway: Afaik TakePhotoAsync will hold like exclusive reading permission on the device so I think you always havebto wait until one taking process finished before starting a new one and can not spam the PhotoCapture with a takePhoto task every frame .. anyway, definitely not in a `while` loop!