# Take several photos with PhotoCapture Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I got a script that should be able to take more than one photo. I am using PhotoCapture and get an error making it unable to capture a second photo. I get the error "Value cannot be null" on the `photoCaptureObject.StartPhotoModeAsync(cameraParameters, result =>` row, but I don't understand why this is.

I have commented away the `photoCaptureObject = null;` row so that the photoCaptureObject should not be null. The row `if (photoCaptureObject == null) return;` also proofs that the `photoCaptureObject`is not null.

```
PhotoCapture photoCaptureObject = null;
Texture2D targetTexture = null;
public string path = "";
CameraParameters cameraParameters = new CameraParameters();

private void Awake()
{
    var cameraResolution = PhotoCapture.SupportedResolutions.OrderByDescending((res) => res.width * res.height).First();
    targetTexture = new Texture2D(cameraResolution.width, cameraResolution.height);

    // Create a PhotoCapture object
    PhotoCapture.CreateAsync(false, captureObject =>
    {
        photoCaptureObject = captureObject;
        cameraParameters.hologramOpacity = 0.0f;
        cameraParameters.cameraResolutionWidth = cameraResolution.width;
        cameraParameters.cameraResolutionHeight = cameraResolution.height;
        cameraParameters.pixelFormat = CapturePixelFormat.BGRA32;
    });
}

private void Update()
{
    // if not initialized yet don't take input
    if (photoCaptureObject == null) return;

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.K) || Input.GetKeyDown("k"))
    {
        Debug.Log("k was pressed");

        VuforiaBehaviour.Instance.gameObject.SetActive(false);

        // Activate the camera
        photoCaptureObject.StartPhotoModeAsync(cameraParameters, result =>
        {
            if (result.success)
            {
                // Take a picture
                photoCaptureObject.TakePhotoAsync(OnCapturedPhotoToMemory);
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.LogError("Couldn't start photo mode!", this);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

There is some code here in between that change the photo taken and so on, but I don't think that that code is part of the problem.

```
private void OnStoppedPhotoMode(PhotoCapture.PhotoCaptureResult result)
{
    // Shutdown the photo capture resource
    VuforiaBehaviour.Instance.gameObject.SetActive(true);
    photoCaptureObject.Dispose();
    //photoCaptureObject = null;
    Debug.Log("Photomode stopped");
}
```

**So what else could be null? Is it the `StartPhotoModeAsync` somehow? How can I fix this issue?**

Thanks!

Comment: You may want to read up on Object.Dispose();

Comment: `StopPhotoModeAsync(OnStoppedPhotoMode)` is called for if that is what you mean? @Henrik It is in another method :) for calling `startPhotomodeAsync` I have to `dispose()` after `StopPhotoModeAsync` to end the instance. but pressing "k" should start a new instance right?

Comment: I just answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55421623/7111561) .. maybe you two should team up ^^

Comment: hahah thanks @derHugo ^.^

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I understand now thanks to Henriks comment.

Unity specifically says this about `StartPhotoModeAsync`:

> Only one PhotoCapture instance can start the photo mode at any given
>   time

I have focused more on the sentence after saying that one should always use `PhotoCapture.StopPhotoModeAsync`because having PhotoCaptureMode on takes more power so I never thought about that the instance wouldn't start again after stopping it.

Now I only have `TakePhotoAsync`in the update on key press and do not stop the PhotoMode due to that the app that I am making should always be able to capture photos.